# Using an ice cream maker with its own compressor

Tags: ice-cream

I'm used to using the ice cream makers where you have to freeze the bowl first, but have now got a used Andrew James model 3368 ice cream makers with its own compressor - but no manual.

I've read about putting a saline solution between the machine and the mixing bowl (I'm guessing for thermal conductivity?), and I know some machines have to get down to temperature before use but I can't see a way to do it with this machine. Do I need to worry about either or is it likely OK to just plug it in and use?

Comment: You can often get manuals online :  https://www.manualslib.com/manual/805283/Andrew-James-Ice-Cream-Maker.html

Comment: I tried that but they don't have this model. They've got another Andrew James model with a compressor (not the one you linked) which doesn't talk about thermal fluids or pre-chilling, but I'm trying to play it safe in case!

Answer (score 3):

Usually with compressor machines you just turn it on and get it super cold, then make sure the dasher is spinning before pouring in the mix. Make sure the mix is below 40°F (4C) beforehand. I also chill down the spoon, container I’m putting the ice cream in, and any add-in’s I’m adding to it. Then spin it until the motor starts slowing down, or until it gets to a firm soft-serve consistency. Enjoy!